# How to use tessdata_fast with C++?

Tags: c++, tesseract

I have been using tesseract integrated with c++ for a project. I want to use tessdata_fast. I cannot find any tutorials anywhere can anyone help?

Comment: Tessa Sanderson may be able to throw some light on to this.

Answer (score 0):

Just point datapath to tessdata_fast directory.